# Can I copy a sheet to a new workbook if it's hidden

Tags: vba, excel

So maybe I'm just not getting something here, but I have a hidden worksheet that list several columns based on other hidden sheets. I'm trying to minimize user intervention... :-)

I want to copy Hidden sheet 1 into a brand new workbook as an available sheet with the aforementioned values. Code that works when hiddensheet is visible:

```
Dim wbNew As Workbook

     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("HiddenSheet").Copy

    Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
    With wbNew
        With .Worksheets(1).UsedRange
            .Value = .Value
        End With
        .SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
        .Close True
     End With
```

So I'd like to still copy the sheet to a new workbook....just want to do it with the sheet hidden.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Turn off screenupdating, unhide sheet, copy the sheet to new workbook, re-hide sheet, turn on screenupdating.

Comment: This is what I came up with as well... Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

is is impossible to copy a hidden sheet to a new workbook
the new workbook would only have 1 sheet (hidden), but every wb needs at least one visible sheet

if you create a visible sheet and copy your hidden sheed later into it, it works

```
Sub Makro1()
  Dim wbNew As Workbook
  Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hidden Sheet").Copy Before:=wbNew.Sheets(1)
End Sub
```

try it :)

Comment: Ok, I guess I had multiple issues going on. I was trying to copy a hidden sheet. I assumed it would by default just appear...So I now understand why I was having the issue. I pretty much just unhide, copy and hide in one sub, no one knows the difference...except for you guys....:-) Thanks.

Comment: its like deleting or hiding your last visible sheet... it cant work at all :)

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely place this line:

```
Worksheets("HiddenSheet").Visible = xlSheetVisible
```

before this line:

```
Worksheets("HiddenSheet").copy
```